# Simple URI redirection / alias in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, wordpress, alias, regex

Please, how can I make this simple operation in Nginx:

I wish that every requests for uris like: 
    http://example.com/adm
or:
    http://example.com/adm
Goes to the wordpress login page:
    wordpress/wp-login.php
(The wordpress installation is inside the folder "wordpress").

I've tried:

```
location /adm/ { alias wordpress/wp-login.php; }
location /adm { alias wordpress/wp-login.php; }
```

and:

```
rewrite ^/adm$ wordpress/wp-login.php;
```

But with no success... The worse here is that some rules, like "rewrite /adm wordpress/wp-login.php;" (that does work!), auto redirects some requests, once the user is logged in, to the default wordpress admin page... And I do not know why...

Just in case someone asks, this is my serve conf. file:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error;

    root /var/www/example.com;

    index index.htm index.php;

    location / {try_files $uri /wp$uri/ /wordpress/index.php$args;}

    location ~ .php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {log_not_found off;access_log off;}
    location = /robots.txt {allow all;log_not_found off;access_log off;}
    location ~ /\. {deny all;access_log off;log_not_found off;  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing but the answer above looked a bit weird to me. For anyone else looking for a solution to this. I ended up using the following:

```
location ~* /login/ {
    rewrite ^/login/(.*)? /wp-admin/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Folks at Nginx Forum helped me to find a solution for that: http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,202235,202475#msg-202475

This is what they came up with:

```
location = /adm/ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

location = /adm {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/wordpress/wp-login.php
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```